# How is new ADA created?

Tags: ada, mint, proof-of-work, proof-of-stake

In a Proof-of-Work protocol, a certain amount of the blockchain's native coin is issued with the minting of a new block as a way to reward miners for their efforts and involvement in the network. As far as I know, though, no coins exist prior to the creation of the genesis block, and after this point, new coins begin to be issued at some rate.

How does this work in a Proof-of-Stake protocol? How does the issuing of new ADA work in Cardano? Was there a certain number of ADA created at the beginning? Or has the 31.9B ADA currently in circulation (out of the 45B max total) all been a product of stake pools forging new blocks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All ADA has already been minted. Technically it was all minted in the first block. The stake pool payouts come from the reserves and transaction fees.

Comment: not the treasury, the "reserves". See [page 2 of the ledger spec](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/6173902/download/1/ledger-spec.pdf). The treasury is for funding the development of Cardano, not for rewards payouts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @EGMSSE is someone "in charge" of the reserves? who or what decides what and how much comes out of them? is it all just managed by the protocol?

Comment: @desolate_mountain Right now, IOHK is managing these variables until the release of [governance](https://cardano.org/governance/) where users will be able to vote to change variables in the protocol. Also you can check out this infographic here: https://i.redd.it/wbmip3szxeg61.jpg to see how rewards are being paid out.